# What is the valid period of using a ros publisher?

Tags: c++, ros

I have the following code for a ros publisher:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  ros::init(argc, argv, "test");
  ros::NodeHandle nh;
  ros::Publisher pub = nh.advertise<std_msgs::Int32>("/test_topic", 1);

  std_msgs::Int32 test_msg;
  test_msg.data = 8;
  pub.publish(test_msg);

  return 0;
}
```

and for a ros subscriber:

```
void test_callback(const std_msgs::Int32 & msg)
{
  std::cout<<msg.data<<std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  ros::init(argc, argv, "test_subscriber");
  ros::NodeHandle nh;
  auto target_sub = nh.subscribe("/test_topic", 1, test_callback);
  ros::spin();
  return 0;
}
```

I manually start the subscriber first, then I run the publisher. But the subscriber does not receive the message. Can anyone help to suggest what is the problem and what might be the cause?

Comment: How do you run your example? Do you have ROS master running?

Comment: In [ROS forum](https://answers.ros.org/question/383696/what-is-first-publisher-or-subscriber/) they say that it should be ok.

Comment: You are not spinning the publisher. However, these questions now belong on robotics.stackexchange.com -- and I'm almost sure there it would be a duplicate.

Comment: @ChristianFritz you do not need to spin for publishers. Publish calls happen async in roscpp, so the issue is most likely that the program exists before fully placing a message on the queue.

Comment: Well, yes, but placing it on the queue is not enough. The way the ROSTCP protocol works is that each subscriber needs to connect to each publisher of the topic in question in order to received messages. So the publisher needs to wait for the subscriber to show up and can only then shut down. From the perspective of the publisher this is an undefined event -- how would it know how long to wait? -- so yes, perhaps you don't need to actually ros.spin but you do need to stay alive for an indefinite amount of time.